# Filemaker Pro 18 Import records from another file

Tags: import, filemaker

I have two filemaker files, one has a set of tables and the other one has the same set of tables and a few more. I want to be able to import all the data from the first fm file to the second one. I know I can use the import function and import it table by table, but since there're around 70 tables so I'm hoping there can be a quicker way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a one-time effort or do you plan to do this periodically?

Comment: @michael.hor257k it's a one time effort

Answer (score 0):

You can copy/paste entire tables (data and structure) between files (provided you have enabled advanced tools in the application's preferences). Hopefully the 70 tables will not exceed your available memory - but you can easily split it into several steps.

Comment: this won't work for me, as the destination table have few extra fields than the original one, sorry wasn't clear of that in my original question

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool, DataMigration tool, that tool is able to make what you are trying to do.

https://support.filemaker.com/s/article/New-FileMaker-data-migration-tool?language=en_US

it is really extremely fast.